# Stop NSDictionary from sorting its items

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sorting, nsdictionary

I have this code

```
NSDictionary *tempDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"authorId","authorName","authorDescription",@"image",nil] forKeys:
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"id",@"name",@"desc",@"image",nil]];
NSLog(@"%@",[tempDict description]);
```

and the output is

```
desc = authorDescription;

id = authorId;

image = image;

name = authorName;
```

You see that the dictionary is sorted by key, alphabetically, for some reason. This is not good for me, because I need to add this dictionary to a plist, and this plist already has some dictionaries with unsorted keys. So how can I avoid this sorting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sorting is due to `[NSDictionary description]`, which is used by `NSLog`. It's not a fundamental feature of `NSDictionary`. If you access the keys through fast enumeration or `[dictionary allKeys]`, you won't find it sorted.

But to your underlying question, if what you want is "unsorted" (random), then "sorted" is just one of the possible random sequences. If you really want unsorted, then sorted shouldn't matter because its a subset.

If sorting matters, then you don't mean "unsorted," you mean "some other sorted order, such as insertion order." If you need `NSDictionary` to be sorted in some way, you need to impose that by converting it into an `NSArray`.

Comment: I am using `[dataDict allKeys]` but still getting random order of my keys.

Comment: @upendra I don't understand the question. There is no order promised for `allKeys`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not sorted. It's displaying in an arbitrary order. Add some more items and you'll probably see the order change.

(It's possible that, internally, the storage is, for some mad reason, actually sorted, but there's nothing you can do about that.)

Comment: ok, I'm writing this dict in plist, opening plist and this dictionary sorted by key (or in an arbitrary order - it does not matter) in plist. It is not acceptable for me

Comment: As lulius said, NSDictionary is not sorting its contents.
NSDictionary is basically a hash table. What you see sorted is its print result only.
If you add your `tempDict` to another dictionary objects/key pairs will be added and they will be stored in no particular order (that is the internals of NSDictionary). 

Alternatively, you can try NSLogging your other NSDictionary that was initialized using your plist, even though its data is not sorted its print out result is sorted too right?